# Find all nodes which are not Roman and all its descendents are roman in a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

**Problem:**
Let T be a binary tree. Define a Roman node to be a node v in T, such that the number of descendants in v’s left subtree differs from the number of nodes in v’s right subtree by at most 5. Describe a linear-time algorithm for finding each node v of T, such that v is not a Roman node, but all of v’s descendants are Roman nodes.

**What I have so far:**
I could think of `O(n^2)` (top-down approach) solution where I will traverse the tree and check if a node is not roman, then traverse this node's descendants to check whether all of them are roman or not. So, in this way I am traversing each node twice.
I am assuming there is a bottom-up approach where it is possible to find the required node in `O(n)`.

Any ideas?

Comment: This bottom-up approach is called postorder. Try calculating two things at each step, e.g. number of nodes in the subtree, and whether all nodes are roman.

Comment: I'm with @n.m. - it's an extra `int` and an extra `bool` at each node, which is probably acceptable...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks @n.m. for your comments. I have implemented a solution using your inputs.

**Logic:**
The basic logic is to set `isRoman` field of a node to `false` even when a node's descendant (suppose grand grand child) is not roman. This means that even if a node satisfies the property (left and right descendants are at most 5) but if its left and right subtree's `isRoman` is `false`, then current node's `isRoman` will also be `false`.

```
/*
 * public class TreeNode {
 * int val;
 * int size;        //stores the number of descendants including itself
 * boolean isRoman; // is true when this node is roman and all its descendants are roman, 
 *                  //false even when a grand grand child node of this node is not roman.
 * TreeNode left;
 * TreeNode right;
 * }
 */
public static void roman(TreeNode root, List<TreeNode> lst){
    if(root == null)
        return;
    if(root.left == null && root.right == null){
        root.size = 1;
        root.isRoman = true;
        return;
    }
    int left = 0;
    int right = 0;
    boolean isLeftRoman = false;
    boolean isRightRoman = false;

    if(root.left != null) {
        roman(root.left,lst);
        left = root.left.size;
        isLeftRoman = root.left.isRoman;
    }else{
     isLeftRoman=true;
    }


    if(root.right != null) {
        roman(root.right,lst);
        right = root.right.size;
        isRightRoman = root.right.isRoman;
    }else{
  isRightRoman=true;
        }

    //if the current node is roman and all it's descendants are roman, update isRoman to true
    if(Math.abs(left-right) <= 5 && isLeftRoman && isRightRoman)
        root.isRoman = true;
    else
        root.isRoman = false;

    //update the current node's size
    root.size = left+right+1;

    //add the node to list which is not roman but all its descendants are roman
    if(Math.abs(left-right) > 5 && isLeftRoman && isRightRoman)
        lst.add(root); 
}
```